# Angular2 extending class and declaring providers

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm using ionic2 and created a class name LoadingService , this class extends LoadingController and define base alert options . in some page I inject it and it's working as expected.
So I decided to take it a step forwarder and add provider decleration to app bootstrap as follow :

```js
ionicBootstrap(MyApp,[

    { provider : LoadingController , useClass : LoadingService}
]);
```

As I run the app I get an error on this line :

> Uncaught Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are
>   allowed, got: [object Object]

My questions are :

- What is this error ?
- In what way can I force the use of LoadingService instead of the
  LoadingController on the app? (if someone injecting LoadingController I want the injector to instantiate and inject the LoadingService)

Answer (score 0):

```
{ provider : LoadingController , useClass : LoadingService }
```

This doesn't match the contract for `Provider`. Why? Because of `provider`. It should be `provide`